# Visual Studio 2013 is giving errors in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I am running on windows 7 64bit Visual studio express 2013 for windows desktop and I am getting errors regarding files in the directory mentioned in the title I have SDL and SOIL linked so that could be causing the problem. I'm not exactly sure what source code to show because the error list maxes out before it talks about any of my files.

It kinda seems like it is trying to compile for windows 8 but I don't want that. I just started with VS coming from Code Blocks and all my code compiled with no problems before.

Also should I be using VS 2012 for windows 7?

Comment: is there an option in VS2013's properties to change the include path?

Comment: @JonnyHenly Maybe but I need a little more help than that. I don't quite know what to look for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to **Project -> Properties**

   [image: Project -> Properties]
2. In **Configuration Properties -> General** set **Platform Toolset** to `Visual Studio 2013 - Windows XP (v120_xp)`.

   [image: Configuration Properties -> General]

If you set this setting to Visual Studio 2013 - Windows XP (v120_xp), then the required library files are read from the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\...` directories.

If you leave it to Visual Studio 2013 (v120), then they are read from the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\...` directories.

Now you can also run your programs (built in the release configuration) on older Windows systems (like Windows XP). **Do this for both debug and release configurations.**

---

#### Images and information gathered from:

[3D C/C++ tutorials - Getting started in Visual Studio Express 2013](http://www.3dcpptutorials.sk/index.php?id=54).

Comment: You nailed it man! Thanks

Comment: @0ctoDragon anytime, let me know if you need anymore help.